# Overlaying an existing object graph?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a database that contains an object graph. However, during use of the objects contained in the database I need to add additional functionality.

I cannot change the classes of the database, so I figure my only option is to make wrapper classes composed of their database equivalent objects and create forwarding methods along with methods and fields for the additional functionality. For instance:

```
public class Foo() {
    private DBFoo databaseFoo;

    // a bunch of forwarding methods to databaseFoo
    // some methods for additional functionality
}
```

I'm struggling with a good pattern to construct my wrapper objects on top of the pre-existing database object graph. In particular how to reconstruct my graph of objects to mirror the graph in the database (with all its various references to other objects). Does anyone have experience with this sort of problem?

Comment: How is this graph initially constructed?

Comment: Can you describe how the existing graph is structured, for e.g. can you get a list of all nodes and edges?

Comment: Don't know if this would help (more details would be nice) but here's a GOF pattern that can be used for adding features are runtime: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1214-designpatterns.html

Comment: I'm not sure what your object structure is like or what extended functionality you need or how you are using the objects, but why couldn't some simple functions inside your class(es) operating on the objects be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems here:

a). Given some dbClassA, which references dbClassB, and collections of dbClassC, with dbClassB and dbClassC each themselves being arbitrarily complex: what design of proxy is appropriate? If dbClassA has methos

```
 dbClassB getB() { ... }
```

we can quite easily see a mapping to

```
 myClassB getB() { return new myClassB( theDbClassB.getB() ); }
```

or some such. But exactly what do we do with the collections?

```
 List<dbClassC> getAllCs() {  }
```

what does that become?

I figure that this is a solvable problem, just a matter of choosing some rules.

I suspect that you're more concerned about:

b). Creating all those proxy classes. Apply the chosen rule to many, many classes. One possible approach is to use code generator capabilities, for example [JET in Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html). I've seen very good use of this capability for similar problems.